# Working Android BLE scan/send/receive example

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm looking for a working example for BLE implementation that scans (finds/connects) and sends/receives messages in either native Android Studio.

I have not found any examples that actually work, most miss core files, most just crash and some do nothing at all.

I apologize if questions like these are not allowed, feel free to delete it or downvote it as you please.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html?hl=zh-cn

Comment: @ReazMurshed That does not work for BLE. Also tried the BluetoothLeGatt example, doesn't find the device either. I downloaded a BT app from the playstore called LightBlue Explorer, this app can connect to the device, I can also send and receive using the app and the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one that scans and sends hardcoded messages:

https://github.com/arpith20/BLEArduino

You can easily update the code in order to have a inputted message sent instead.

In order to read messages sent to the app, add the following to the BroadcastReceiver in the DeviceControlActivity Line: 132

```
else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
     String value = intent.getExtras().getString(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA);
     messages += value;
     tvMessages.setText(messages);
  }
```